# Getting undefined control sequence with a simple \color{red}\sout{text}} command

Tags: errors, color

I'm running the following simple code which contains two commands that are pretty much the same ({\color{red}..).  However, I can't figure out why the second one gives an "undefined control sequence" error while the first one does not (I marked it using a comment):

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\cellem}{\cellcolor{gray}\color{white}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\begin{document}




%COMPILES  
    {\color{red}\sout{and is an order of magnitude}}

        %DOES NOT COMPILE
    {\color{red}\sout{Comparisons are provided using a wide range of relevant alternative methods. These include the early, ``pure''-binary descriptors: BRIEF~\cite{calonder2010brief}, BRISK~\cite{leutenegger2011brisk}, FREAK~\cite{alahi2012freak}, and ORB~\cite{rublee2011orb}. We additionally provide results comparing LATCH to the more computationally expensive BinBoost~\cite{lepetit2013boosting,trzcinski2013learning}, LDA-Hash~\cite{strecha2012ldahash}, DBRIEF~\cite{trzcinski2012efficient} and A-KAZE~\cite{Alcantarilla13bmvc}. Finally, the performance of SIFT~\cite{lowe2004distinctive} and SURF~\cite{bay2006surf} are also provided as baseline methods.}}



\end{document}
```

Can someone please give me any clue as to why the second latex line does not compile?

Thanks,

Gil.

Comment: please post a complete small document that shows the problem, you haven't even said which command is undefined, and we can't run the code fragment so hard to offer help

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). When asking questions it is better to give a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should look like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves a lot of time for everyone.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, indeed the question was quite vague (it's the late hour, sorry:) . I updated the question with some working code. Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving an undefined control sequence error? I can't reproduce the problem with your current code. Perhaps delete the `.aux` and `.bbl` file and try to recompile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ulem documentation suggests hiding `\cite` in `\mbox` and this seems to work:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\cellem}{\cellcolor{gray}\color{white}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}




%COMPILES  
    {\color{red}\sout{and is an order of magnitude}}

        %DOES NOT COMPILE
    {\color{red}\sout{Comparisons are provided using a wide range of relevant alternative methods.
These include the early, ``pure''-binary descriptors: BRIEF~\mbox{\cite{calonder2010brief}}, 
BRISK~\cite{leutenegger2011brisk}, FREAK~\mbox{\cite{alahi2012freak}}, and ORB~\mbox{\cite{rublee2011orb}}. 
We additionally provide results comparing LATCH to the more computationally expensive 
BinBoost~\mbox{\cite{lepetit2013boosting,trzcinski2013learning}}, LDA-Hash~\mbox{\cite{strecha2012ldahash}}, 
DBRIEF~\mbox{\cite{trzcinski2012efficient}} and A-KAZE~\mbox{\cite{Alcantarilla13bmvc}}. Finally, 
the performance of SIFT~\mbox{\cite{lowe2004distinctive}} and 
SURF~\mbox{\cite{bay2006surf}} are also provided as baseline methods.}}

\end{document}
```